# How to append a column name to pandas.core.indexes.base.Index

Tags: pandas, indexing, append

Thanks for looking at my problem. I want to add target column to new_thing, what should I do. Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
# reading data from csv
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df.head()
# The csv format
# ID    cot1    num1    target  num2    cat3
# 0 123 Santa Elena 100 1   52.00   a
# 1 124 India   77  1   25.00   d
# 2 125 Ruanda  60  0   32.10   b
# 3 126 Lesoto  11  0   -11.00  h
# 4 127 Singapur    79  0   0.07    j

df.dtypes
# diffrent columns category(int,string)
# out
# ID          int64
# cot1       object
# num1        int64
# target      int64
# num2      float64
# cat3       object
# dtype: object

new_thing = df.select_dtypes(include = ['object']).columns

new_thing

# out 
# Index(['cot1', 'cat3'], dtype='object')
type(new_thing)
# out 
#pandas.core.indexes.base.Index
# I want to add target column to the new_thing
# I have tried the below but no success
new_thing.append(df.target)
# 
# TypeError: all inputs must be Index
```

As you see I could not add the target to new_thing

Comment: Please paste your actual, not images.

Answer (score 0):

This `error` is because `new_thing` store values of **type** `pandas.DataFrame.index` (columns) if you want to add `'target'` to `new_thing` you must do this

```
new_thing = df.select_dtypes(include = ['object']).columns
new_thing.append(df.columns[df.columns.get_loc("target")])
```

to add column and rows selecting type `object` you should not use instance `.columns`

```
new_thing = df.select_dtypes(include = ['object'])
print(pd.concat([new_thing, df[['target']]]))
```